# Threesum algorithm with Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

The question is - how many three numbers exits (of the provided) that sum to zero?

I'm wondering, how to implement this brute force method (below) in ruby? The main  aspect of this  is : what is better to use in a place of for loop? times?
a - is array of integers, the data that's provided

```
int N = a.length;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
  for(int j = i+1; j<N; j++)
    for(int k = j+ 1; k<N; k++)
      if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0 )
        count++;
return count;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
a.combination(3).count{|x,y,z| x+y+z==0}
```

But I don't get the connection with Rails here ;)

Comment: While this solution is shorter than the original, efficiency wise, it is just as bad, and you would certainly fail if you suggested this during a coding interview (which is typically what this question is used for)

Answer (score 1):

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
    seen = Hash.new
    result = []
    nums.each_with_index do |e, i|
        if seen.has_key?(target-e)
            result << [seen[target-e], i]
        else
            seen[e] = i
        end
    end
    return result
end

def three_sum(nums)
    nums.sort!
    seen = Hash.new
    results = []
    nums.each_with_index do |e, i|
        if !seen.has_key?(e)
            two_sum(nums[i + 1 .. -1], 0 - e).each do |pair|
                results << [e] + pair.map{ |j| nums[j + i + 1] }
            end
            seen[e] = i
        end
    end
    return results.count
end
```